# Show loading dialog while running background operation Android

Tags: android, background, android-asynctask, loading

i need to do some image processing on android which involves pixel by pixel editing. This takes a little too long and the screen just freezes there so i wanted to do a loading dialog so the let the user know that the program is still running.

This editPhoto function is what i need to run in background.

```
 private void editPhoto() {
    if (editPhotoImg.getDrawable() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Photo Selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (hasSample == false) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Sample Photo Selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {


        detectFaces(false);


        BitmapDrawable ebm = (BitmapDrawable) editPhotoImg.getDrawable();

        Bitmap editTemp = ebm.getBitmap();
        PointF editFaceMidPoint = getFaceMidPoint(editTemp);

        BitmapDrawable sbm = (BitmapDrawable) samplePhotoImg.getDrawable();
        Bitmap sampleTemp = sbm.getBitmap();
        PointF sampleFaceMidPoint = getFaceMidPoint(sampleTemp);

        if (editFaceMidPoint != null && sampleFaceMidPoint != null) {
            int editFaceMidPointPixel = editTemp.getPixel(
                    (int) editFaceMidPoint.x, (int) editFaceMidPoint.y);
            int sampleFaceMidPointPixel = sampleTemp.getPixel(
                    (int) sampleFaceMidPoint.x, (int) sampleFaceMidPoint.y);

            editPhotoImg.setImageBitmap(shiftRGB(editTemp,
                    editFaceMidPointPixel, sampleFaceMidPointPixel));

            savePhoto();

            detectFaces(true);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my AsyncTask code which does not achieve what i want. It gives me an error that i couldn't even identify. Can someone tell me what should i do, or where should i be calling the editPhoto() method so that it will be running behind a loading dialog and not before or after the loading dialog?

```
     private class LoadEditPhoto extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    // Before running code in separate thread

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        /* Create a new progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditPhoto.this);
        // Set the progress dialog to display a horizontal progress bar
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        // Set the dialog title to 'Loading...'
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        // Set the dialog message to 'Loading application View, please
        // wait...'
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading application View, please wait...");
        */
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(EditPhoto.this,"Loading...",  
                "Editing Photo, please wait...", false, false);  
        // This dialog can't be canceled by pressing the back key
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // This dialog isn't indeterminate
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // The maximum number of items is 100
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        // Set the current progress to zero
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        // Display the progress dialog
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    // The code to be executed in a background thread.
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        /*
         * This is just a code that delays the thread execution 4 times,
         * during 850 milliseconds and updates the current progress. This is
         * where the code that is going to be executed on a background
         * thread must be placed.
         * 
         */


        editPhoto();
        publishProgress(100);
        return null;
    }

    // Update the progress
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // set the current progress of the progress dialog
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    // after executing the code in the thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // close the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the toast messages and it should work. you can't update UI from `doInBackground` method. Other than that your code looks fine. So this should be the bug,.

or use runOnUi() to show your Toast messages.

Surround your toast like this,

```
ActivityObject.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Andro, thank you for the suggestion. But somehow this is still not working for me. It crashes with a windowleaked error hmm

Comment: its because you have used application context. instead use the Activity's context for the toast. Something like this, Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 1):

Put your `editPhoto()` in  **Thread** .

Now define following code to handle multiple messages.

```
public enum WhatAbout {
    START,STOP
}

public WhatAbout[] wa = WhatAbout.values();
```

Then use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), which helps you to communicate `BackgroundThread` and `UIThread`.
Without using handler, you can't change `UI`.

Put following code in your `onCreate` method.

```
handler = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what < wa.length) {
    switch (wa[msg.what]) 
    {
    case START:
         progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null,
                        "Editing Photo... Please Wait...");
         break;

    case STOP:
         if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();

         imageView.setImageBitmap(editedBitmap);
         break;
    }
  }
};
```

Then when your  ***editing started***  in `Thread`, place following code at the first line of `editPhoto()`.

```
handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(
                WhatAbout.START.ordinal(), 0, 0));
```

When your `editing` completed, place following code at the end of `editPhoto()`.

```
handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(
                WhatAbout.STOP.ordinal(), 0, 0));
```

Comment: Chintan, thanks for the kind explanation! But being new to android programming, i still couldn't implement it despite how step by step you described. I posted my codes below again